# Rails Kaminari example infinite scroll not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to implement kaminari rails infinite scroll using this example.
It is working fine in my other apps but not working in this app. 
[Kaminari example](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/wiki/How-To:-Create-Infinite-Scrolling-with-jQuery)

My company controller

```
def index
  @companies = Company.all.page(params[:page]).per(4)
end
```

My index.html.erb

```
<div class="posts">
 <div class="page">
  <%= render @companies %>
 </div>
</div>
<%= paginate @companies %>
```

My _company.html.erb

```
<div class="post">
<% company_decorator = CompanyDecorator.new(company)%>
    <h4><%= company.name %> || 
            No. of operations:  <%= company_decorator.number_of_operations %> ||
            Average Amount : <%= company_decorator.average_of_amount %> ||
            Highest of Month: <%= company_decorator.highest_of_month%> ||
            Accepted Operations: <%= company_decorator.accepted_operations%>
    </h4>
    <ul>
        <% company.operations.each do |operation| %>
            <li><%= operation.id%></li>

        <%end%>
    </ul>   
</div>
```

My assets/javascripts/companies.js.coffee

```
$(document).ready ->
  $(".posts .page").infinitescroll
    navSelector: "nav.pagination"
    nextSelector: "nav.pagination a[rel=next]"
    itemSelector: ".posts .post"
```

My index.js.erb

```
$(".posts").append("<div class='page'><%= escape_javascript(render(@companies)) %></div>");
```

I am unable to find problem please help me. This same code is working in my other app.

Comment: What does "not working" mean, specifically?  Is there an error?  If so, please include the error information in your question.  Is the Javascript code not running?  If so, please describe how you determine that.  Are there browser console messages?  If so, please include them in your question.

Comment: @MichaelGaskill Its not showing up any error. Plugin is not working and showing normal pagination.

Comment: Have you confirmed that jQuery runs?  Put a console message before `$(document).ready` in your .coffee file, and then put one inside `$(document).ready`, but before the `.infinitescroll` call.  See if they show up to the console.  If `console.log("here");` doesn't work for you, try `alert("here")`.  This will confirm that the Javascript is being executed, AND that `$(document).ready` is called.  It's a first step to debugging Javascript issues.

Comment: @MichaelGaskill I think jquery is not loading. How can i fix it ?
I have proper //= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs in application.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try 

`def index
  @companies = Company.all.page(params[:page]).per(25)
end`

playing with the pagination length.. I've heard that sometimes works